# Magento 302 when accesing installation

Tags: php, magento, apache2

I've installed magento countless times and been getting the same error. When trying to access the installation, magento sends a 302 redirect to the first ip it got installed in ( 192.168.10.144 ). I feel like I tried every trick in the book.

- there is no /tmp/magento folder on my machine.
- deleted several times /var/www/html/magento/var/cache and /var/www/html/magento/var/session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has a default behaviour to auto redirects you to his **Base URL**.
If you want to change it, open up your Magento DB and in the table `core_config_data` your old IP *192.168.10.144* should appear as value for the path `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`.

Just change it to the new IP or URL you want there, then clean your caches again, and voila.

If you just want to reinstall it, just delete all the table and the file `app/etc/local.xml` and you should be able to run through the install process again.

Comment: correct! I ended up dropping the db entirely and then it did just fine.